# Having trouble compiling a tally from a table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm an amateur user of MS Access to create some databases for work.  I'm currently trying to make a database to track people that are in quarantine due to potential exposure to COVID-19.  I have the input stuff down but I need help with tallying up the numbers to get the output that we need.  I can't access this site at work and I'm working off of memory at home so please bear with me.  The part where I'm consistently getting errors is with a line similar to:

TallyRecordset![Contractor Pos not Hos] = 0

I'm getting an error that I think is saying that its not defined but again I'm going off of memory and I think it was error 3021.  I've tried coming at this from several different ways already using nesting if/then statements (because the above would look a contractor that had tested positive but was not hospitalized so its not a straight count) and having the tally go directly to the table that I made for tallies with the fields as numbers and it didn't work.  So then I thought that creating an integer variable and making those equal to the fields in the table that I changed to strings would fix the issue but I got the same error.  After googling the problem for a couple of days and getting no solutions that make sense to me I'm not even sure that I'm going about this the right way.  I'm guessing that I have to do something with queries but I have no idea.  Thanks for taking the time to read this and for any input that you have.

Edit: The error that I get is:

> Run-time error '3021': No current record

.  It highlights the line:

`CountRecordset.Edit`

I'm trying to get an output that is easy to copy and paste into a table in PowerPoint for a slide.

```
Private Sub Command18_Click()

    Dim TrackingDatabase As Database, TrackingRecordset As Recordset
    Set TrackingDatabase = CurrentDb
    Set TrackingRecordset = TrackingDatabase.OpenRecordset("Roster", dbOpenDynaset)

    TrackingRecordset.MoveFirst
    While Not TrackingRecordset.EOF
        If TrackingRecordset![Quarrantined Until at Least] > Date Then
            Dim NotTrackingDatabase As Database, NotTrackingRecordset As Recordset
            Set NotTrackingDatabase = CurrentDb
            Set NotTrackingRecordset = NotTrackingDatabase.OpenRecordset("Formerly Tracked People", dbOpenDynaset)
            NotTrackingRecordset.AddNew
                NotTrackingRecordset![Status] = TrackingRecordset![Status]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Last Name] = TrackingRecordset![Last Name]
                NotTrackingRecordset![First Name] = TrackingRecordset![First Name]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Rank] = TrackingRecordset![Rank]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Unit] = TrackingRecordset![Unit]
                NotTrackingRecordset![DoD ID Number] = TrackingRecordset![DoD ID Number]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Age] = TrackingRecordset![Age]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Case Number] = TrackingRecordset![Case Number]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Confirmed Case] = TrackingRecordset![Confirmed Case]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Hospitalized] = TrackingRecordset![Hospitalized]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Asymptomatic] = TrackingRecordset![Asymptomatic]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Symptomatic] = TrackingRecordset![Symptomatic]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Date of Symptoms] = TrackingRecordset![Date of Symptoms]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Date of Last Contact] = TrackingRecordset![Date of Last Contact]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Quarrantined Until at Least] = TrackingRecordset![Quarrantined Until at Least]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Date of Notification] = TrackingRecordset![Date of Notification]
                NotTrackingRecordset![Notes] = TrackingRecordset![Notes]
            NotTrackingRecordset.Update
            Call NotTrackingRecordset.Close
            TrackingRecordset.Delete
            TrackingRecordset.MoveNext
        Else
            TrackingRecordset.MoveNext
        End If
    Wend

    Dim DependentsRecovered, DependentsQnotPos, DependentsQPos, DependentsPosnotHos, DependentsPosHos As Integer
    Dim OtherContractorRecovered, OtherContractorQnotPos, OtherContractorQPos, OtherContractorPosnotHos, OtherContractorPosHos As Integer
    Dim TotalRecovered, TotalQnotPos, TotalQPos, TotalPosnotHos, TotalPosHos As Integer

    DependentsRecovered = 0
    DependentsQnotPos = 0
    DependentsQPos = 0
    DependentsPosnotHos = 0
    DependentsPosHos = 0
    OtherContractorRecovered = 0
    OtherContractorQnotPos = 0
    OtherContractorQPos = 0
    OtherContractorPosnotHos = 0
    OtherContractorPosHos = 0
    TotalRecovered = 0
    TotalQnotPos = 0
    TotalQPos = 0
    TotalPosnotHos = 0
    TotalPosHos = 0

    TrackingRecordset.MoveFirst
    While Not TrackingRecordset.EOF
        If TrackingRecordset![Status] = "Other Contractor" Then
            If TrackingRecordset![Confirmed Case] = "Yes" Then
                OtherContractorQPos = OtherContractorQPos + 1
                If TrackingRecordset![Hospitalized] = "Yes" Then
                    OtherContractorPosHos = OtherContractorPosHos + 1
                    TrackingRecordset.MoveNext
                Else
                    OtherContractorPosnotHos = OtherContractorPosnotHos + 1
                    TrackingRecordset.MoveNext
                End If
            Else
                OtherContractorQnotPos = OtherContractorQnotPos + 1
                TrackingRecordset.MoveNext
            End If
        Else
            If TrackingRecordset![Confirmed Case] = "Yes" Then
                DependentsQPos = DependentsQPos + 1
                If TrackingRecordset![Hospitalized] = "Yes" Then
                    DependentsPosHos = DependentsPosHos + 1
                    TrackingRecordset.MoveNext
                Else
                    DependentsPosnotHos = DependentsPosnotHos + 1
                    TrackingRecordset.MoveNext
                End If
            Else
                DependentsQnotPos = DependentsQnotPos + 1
                TrackingRecordset.MoveNext
            End If
        End If
    Wend

    Call TrackingRecordset.Close

    Set NotTrackingDatabase = CurrentDb
    Set NotTrackingRecordset = NotTrackingDatabase.OpenRecordset("Formerly Tracked People", dbOpenDynaset)

    NotTrackingRecordset.MoveFirst
    While Not NotTrackingRecordset.EOF
        If NotTrackingRecordset![Status] = "Other Contractor" Then
            If NotTrackingRecordset![Confirmed Case] = "Yes" Then
                If NotTrackingRecordset![Hospitalized] = "Yes" Then
                    OtherContractorPosHos = OtherContractorPosHos + 1
                    OtherContractorRecovered = OtherContractorRecovered + 1
                    NotTrackingRecordset.MoveNext
                Else
                    OtherContractorPosnotHos = OtherContractorPosnotHos + 1
                    OtherContractorRecovered = OtherContractorRecovered + 1
                    NotTrackingRecordset.MoveNext
                End If
            Else
                NotTrackingRecordset.MoveNext
            End If
        Else
            If NotTrackingRecordset![Confirmed Case] = "Yes" Then
                If NotTrackingRecordset![Hospitalized] = "Yes" Then
                    DependentsPosHos = DependentsPosHos + 1
                    DependentsRecovered = DependentsRecovered + 1
                    NotTrackingRecordset.MoveNext
                Else
                    DependentsPosnotHos = DependentsPosnotHos + 1
                    DependentsRecovered = DependentsRecovered + 1
                    NotTrackingRecordset.MoveNext
                End If
            Else
                NotTrackingRecordset.MoveNext
            End If
        End If
    Wend

    Call NotTrackingRecordset.Close

    TotalRecovered = DependentsRecovered + OtherContractorRecovered
    TotalQnotPos = DependentsQnotPos + OtherContractorQnotPos
    TotalQPos = DependentsQPos + OtherContractorQPos
    TotalPosnotHos = DependentsPosnotHos + OtherContractorPosnotHos
    TotalPosHos = DependentsPosHos + OtherContractorPosHos

    Dim CountDatabase As Database, CountRecordset As Recordset
    Set CountDatabase = CurrentDb
    Set CountRecordset = CountDatabase.OpenRecordset("Counts", dbOpenDynaset)

    CountRecordset.Edit
        CountRecordset![Total Recovered] = TotalRecovered
        CountRecordset![Total Q not Pos] = TotalQnotPos
        CountRecordset![Total Q Pos] = TotalQPos
        CountRecordset![Total Pos not Hos] = TotalPosnotHos
        CountRecordset![Total Pos Hos] = TotalPosHos
        CountRecordset![Dependents Recovered] = DependentsRecovered
        CountRecordset![Dependents Q not Pos] = DependentsQnotPos
        CountRecordset![Dependents Q Pos] = DependentsQPos
        CountRecordset![Dependents Pos not Hos] = DependentsPosnotHos
        CountRecordset![Dependents Pos Hos] = DependentsPosHos
        CountRecordset![Other Contractor Recovered] = OtherContractorRecovered
        CountRecordset![Other Contractor Q not Pos] = OtherContractorQnotPos
        CountRecordset![Other Contractor Q Pos] = OtherContractorQPos
        CountRecordset![Other Contractor Pos not Hos] = OtherContractorPosnotHos
        CountRecordset![Other Contractor Pos Hos] = OtherContractorPosHos
    CountRecordset.Update

    Call CountRecordset.Close
```

Comment: Suggest you note details of error message, where that expression is used, data structure and desired output as text tables and edit question with that info. If this is a query, then provide SQL statement. If VBA, then post code.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I've updated the original question with everything that you asked for I think.  I cut out a bunch of repetitive code to make it a bit easier.  As I said, I'm not even sure if this is the best way to do this.

Comment: Did not provide data tables. Most likely there is simpler way to accomplish but without sample data and desired result tables, hard to say what. The added info does not show the line you originally said was issue. The error on recordset Edit likely means CountRecordset has no records to edit. Why would Counts not have any records?

Comment: For one thing, instead of looping code to do tally, why not an aggregate query with filter criteria? Or DCount() domain aggregate function?

Comment: I can't provide the actual data tables because its medical information.  Each entry would have a person's name, age, status (or job I suppose), if they're symptomatic or asymptomatic, if they're a confirmed COVID case, and if they're hospitalized or not. 
 The code that was edited out at the top was essentially for removing people that were past the 14 day quarantine period and putting them into a "Not Tracking" table.  I'll have to take a look at those two methods as I haven't used them before.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: CountRecordset didn't have any entries because that's what I'm trying to do.  All of this is to populate that table.  Not sure if that changes your opinion on what to do.

Comment: Then you want AddNew, not Edit. Use fake but realistic (e.g. Mickey Mouse) data in samples.